# bounded loops in ebpf. Does now the verifier check if the program is a DAG?

Tags: c, kernel, bpf, ebpf

Since bounded loop are now allowed in ebpf programs https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/davem/net-next.git/commit/?id=2589726d12a1b12eaaa93c7f1ea64287e383c7a5
does the verifier still check in the first pass if the program control flow is a Direct Acyclic Graph?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, [it still does](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1e3778cb223e861808ae0daccf353536e7573eed/kernel/bpf/verifier.c#L9289), and rejects programs with back-edges in two cases:

- If the program is loaded by an **unprivileged user**. The [`env->allow_ptr_leaks`](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1e3778cb223e861808ae0daccf353536e7573eed/kernel/bpf/verifier.c#L6248) boolean indicates a privileged user.
- If the back-edge is [performed using a call](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1e3778cb223e861808ae0daccf353536e7573eed/kernel/bpf/verifier.c#L6311). **Only normal jumps can make bounded loops** (which doesn't mean you can't do a bpf-to-bpf call *inside* a bounded loop).

Comment: Thank you very much, it's really hard for me to understand that code :( Is also rejected if the loops is to big I imagine right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The verifier counts every instruction it verifies and when it reaches one million (for privileged users), it rejects the program. So a 4 instructions loop of 250001 iterations would be rejected.

Comment: Ok so 1 million limit is just for root and 130k for normal users right? And that numbers refer to all the possible instructions that the verifier can explore. I've read that and also that an eBPF program can't be larger than BPF_MAXINSNS but I don't understand why there is just one which value is 4096. I'd expect another BPF_MAXINSNS for root .

Comment: I think the maximum number of instructions the verifier can explore is 1 million for both privileged and unprivileged users actually. The [maximum program size](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/1e3778cb223e861808ae0daccf353536e7573eed/kernel/bpf/syscall.c#L1640) is 1 million for privileged users and 4096 for unprivileged.